# Real-time Html Edtior with iFrame (what I am doing wrong)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have been trying to create real time html editer using iframe and textarea but for some reason my code does not work as expacted.

could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var old = '';

 function update(){
  var textarea = document.getElementById('code');
  var iFrame = document.getElementById('output').contentWindow.document;

  if (old != textarea.value){
    old = textarea.value;
    iFrame.clear();
    iFrame.write(old);
  }

  window.setTimeout(update, 150);
 }
```

html

```
  <body onload="update()">

  <textarea id="code"></textarea>

  <iframe id="output"></iframe>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```js
var old = '';
 function update(){
  var textarea = document.getElementById('code');
  var iFrame = document.getElementById('output');
  var IframeDocument=document.getElementById('output').contentDocument
  if (old != textarea.value){
    old = textarea.value;
    iFrame.src="about:blank";
    IframeDocument.write(old);
  }

  window.setTimeout(update, 150);
 }
 window.onload=update();
```

```html
<body >
  <textarea id="code"></textarea>
  <iframe id="output"></iframe>
</body>
```

Here is the [FiddleDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/jLm031m3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it did not work for me.

Comment: U tried the fiddle demo? And if it didnt work for you then there is something that you forgot to share some special case or some special condition..

Comment: I tried the Fiddle demo, and it did almost work!! the problem was that the iframe was updating once after typing to characters